# Object has no attributes

Tags: python

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value=value
        self.left=None
        self.right=None

class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self,values):
        length=len(values)
        node=[]
        for x in range(length):
            node.append(Node(values[x]))
        for x in range(length):
            if 2*x+1 < length:
                node[x].left = node[2*x+1]
            if 2*x+2 < length:
                node[x].right = node[2*x+2]
        if node[0] != None:
            self.root = node[0]
        else:
            self.root = None

    def DFS(self,node,obj):
        if node == None or node.value == obj:
            return node
        else:
            self.DFS(node.left,obj)
            self.DFS(node.right,obj)

def main():
    obj = raw_input("Please input a number you want to search: ")
    tree = Tree(range(100))
    node = tree.DFS(tree.root,obj)
    if node.value == obj:
        print "I've done it!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Hi, I am new to python and this platform. I want to realize DFS in my python 'Tree' class but the shell says 'Tree' object has no attribute 'DFS'. However, DFS is explicitly defined in my code. Can any one help me with this? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Executing your code, I get a different error message:

```
    if node.value == obj:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
```

This error message is because `Tree.DFS()` doesn't actually always return anything explicitly (and so `None` is returned), and `None` doesn't have a `value` attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much for your instant answer! It turns out that my sublime text editor's indentation setting was wrong so the function DFS was not actually defined as a method of class Tree. Many thanks for your help! BTW, how to input code like yours, which has gray background  in comment box?

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to see the problem that you state. I get an error from this:

```
def DFS(self,node,obj):
    if node == None or node.value == obj:
        return node
```

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'`

When the `node == None` it is returning `None`, which can't/doesn't have the `value` attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much for your instant answer! It turns out that my sublime text editor's indentation setting was wrong so the function DFS was not actually defined as a method of class Tree. Many thanks for your help! BTW, how to input code like yours, which has gray background in comment box?